# expected a; but I already have a ;

Tags: c++

hello I am trying to do my college homework but I keep getting an error saying expected a `;` but I already have a `;` on that line. my error is during the cin answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name;
cout << "Welcome to the Prison of Elders, Guardian, what is your name ?.";
cin  >> name;

cout << "are you ready to face a challenge" << name <<  "!" << endl;
cin answer; 


while (1);
return 0;
```

Comment: s/`cin answer; `/`cin >> answer; `

Comment: You have a mistake: `cin answer; `

Comment: thanks guys, I was confused on this I should have added the >>

Answer (score 3):

```
cin answer;
```

should be replaced by

```
cin >> answer;
```

**More generally, the "expected thing" as compiler message should always be treated with caution**. It's just some guess that matches the syntax from the compiler. However, it is always the sign of a **syntax error somewhere**. (And not necessarily at the line where you see the "expected thing")

To elaborate on why ";" was expected :
`cin` is an identifier, as well as `answer`

You wrote `identifier identifier;`, which is never a correct syntax in C++.

the compilator was confused by seeing two identifiers next to each other. So it suggested this :

```
cin; answer;
```

which is syntactically correct and solve the confusion, but complete nonsense semantically in your code.